# Word macro: Insert text into each selected cell of a table

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I am trying to format cells and insert text (in this case a checkbox) in each SELECTED cell in a table. This is used as a place keeping aid in my plant emergency procedures. The cells format properly, but the text will only insert in the FIRST selected cell. I am a complete amateur at writing macros, and do not know how to create a loop to go to each selected cell. I have been unable to find a suitable answer.

Because the areas where checkboxes are needed can be scattered all over the place due to the nature of the procedures, I need to be able to manually select multiple cells in different locations. I can't just specify a whole row or column.

Example VBA:

```
Sub CkBox2()
'
' CkBox2 Macro
' Inserts check box in each SELECTED cell.
'
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6

Selection.Font.Size = 14
Selection.TypeText Text:=""
Selection.InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings", CharacterNumber:=168, Unicode:=True

End Sub
```

Using this, I end up with only one checkbox in the first selected cell: (see Figure 1 below)

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyq7j.png)

Comment: I would advise posting this under the vba and microsoft word tags in the stackoverflow site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word That is the site for troubleshooting programming. If you do, please delete the question here. You want to look to using the Range rather than the Selection object.

Comment: As written, you can't. Word VBA doesn't support a Selection consisting of multiple non-contiguous cells. However, instead of selecting multiple cells and then running a macro, you could define a keyboard shortcut for your current macro. Then you can simply select each cell and hit the shortcut. Or even better: define a bullet style and give that a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually possible to access the various parts of a non-contiguous Select directly using VBA. Nor can you do somethng like "iterate the cells, detect selected cells, and add them to a list for later processing and see which of them is selected". Broadly speaking, when you try to do that, you end up dealing with the *last* part of the Selection, and that's it.

What does work is to use Selection.Paste to paste the contents of the clipboard into multiple cells. But to do that, you first have to insert whatever you want somewhere in your document and copy it into the clipboard, then paste it into the Selection. Which complicates the process.

From a coding point of view, perhaps easier to try to "mark" each cell by inserting a "magic text" into each selected cell, find those cells, and insert what you really want instead.

For example,

```
Sub MultipleSelection1()
'
'
' insert an unlikely piece of text  ("magic text") somewhere in the document and copy it into the clipboard

Const MAGIC As String = "zmagic"
Dim c As Word.Cell
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim t As Integer
Set r = ActiveDocument.Characters.Last
r.Text = MAGIC
' exclude the paragraph/section marker
r.End = r.End - 1
' copy the text
r.Copy
' delete the inserted text
r.Delete
Set r = Nothing

' paste into all the selected cells
Selection.Paste

' iterate the cells containing the magic text

' If the selection is only ever in a single table, you *could* then use

For Each c In Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells

' or if you don't mind iterating all the cells in the document you could loop through all the cells in each table.
' Unfortunately you can't just use "ActiveDocument.Range.Cells"

' NB sometimes better to count backwords, i.e. .count to 1.
'For t = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
'For Each c In ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Range.Cells

  If Left(c.Range.Text, Len(MAGIC)) = MAGIC Then
    Set r = c.Range
    r.End = r.End - 1
    ' do whatever you want to this cell, e.g.
    With r
      .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
      .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
      .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
      .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6

      .Font.Size = 14
      .Text = ""
      .InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings", CharacterNumber:=168, Unicode:=True
    End With
    Set r = Nothing
  End If
Next

' Uncomment this if you are iterating all the tables
'Next
    
End Sub
```

Or you could use Find to iterate through each "Magic Text", like this:

```
Sub MultipleSelection2()
'
'
' insert an unlikely piece of text  ("magic text") somewhere in the document and copy it into the clipboard

Const MAGIC As String = "zmagic"

Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim c As Word.Cell
Dim r As Word.Range
bFound = True
Set r = ActiveDocument.Characters.Last
r.Text = MAGIC
' exclude the paragraph/section marker
r.End = r.End - 1
' copy the text
r.Copy
' delete the inserted text
r.Delete
Set r = Nothing

' paste into all the selected cells
Selection.Paste

' iterate all instances of the magic text

Set r = ActiveDocument.Content
With r.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   Do While bFound
     .Text = MAGIC
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindStop
     bFound = .Execute()
     If bFound Then
       ' do whatever you want to the found text
       With r
         .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
         .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
         .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
         .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6

         .Font.Size = 14
         .Text = ""
         .InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings", CharacterNumber:=168, Unicode:=True
       End With
    End If
  Loop
End With
Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```